# Regional On Jquery Datepicker - Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have date.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#school_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  $("#school_date").datepicker("option",
      $.datepicker.regional["id"])
```

but not working..

How to add regional on jquery datapicker?

Comment: The desired localization file should be included after the main datepicker code. and `$("#school_tanggal").datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );`

Comment: ok thanks. I forgot to include http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired localization file should be included after the main datepicker code and 
initailize the script

```
$("#school_tanggal").datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ]);
```